# Not able to detect browser using Modernizer

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I'm recently looking all my project jquery to the latest version and I hit a road block when I heard that `$.browser` is deprecated and removed from the latest jquery version

So I decide to use modernizer to achieve the same but I somehow was not able to get the browser 
object when I run this `$.browser` on console instead I get undefined

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TD5uh/9/) output describing the same

Any thing that I'm doing wrong

Comment: Have you stopped a minute to wonder why `$.browser` was removed, and why Modernizr puts so much effort into providing feature detection instead of user agent sniffing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Browser detection* vs *Feature Detection*

*Or [Why is browser sniffing not a recommended practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661213/why-is-browser-sniffing-not-a-recommended-practice)*

I recomend you some research about *Feature Detection*, and why it's better than *Browser Detection* or *Browser Sniffing*. [This article on the  jQuery learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/) explains both techniques, and why feature detection is better than browser detection.

To summarize, quoting the article I refer:

### Browser detection

> Browser detection is a method where the browser's User Agent (UA) string is checked for
>   a particular pattern unique to a browser family or version.

### Feature detection

> Specific feature detection checks if a specific feature is available, instead of
>   developing against a specific browser. This way, developers can write their
>   code for two cases: the browser **does** support said feature, or the browser
>   **does not** support said feature.

While *Browser detection* seems to be an easy solution, there are several problems:

- **Other browsers other than your target may have the same issue**.
  If we target a specific browser for different functionality, we implicitly
  exclude any browser we did not account for.
- **User Agents are unreliable**.
  User Agents are set by the client browser and are also user-configurable. While
  the user may change this string, the browser's feature support remains the same.

---

As said by @Garath on his answer, I recomend you [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as feature detection library. You can also take a look at [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), but the jQuery team does not recommend using it as it's intended for jQuery's internal use.

Comment: Interesting I never thought on those line

Answer (score 1):

Using Modernizer you can check if some functionality of HTML5 is available in selected browser. It is not a library to bring back `$.browser`

If you need to bring back `$.browser` you can use: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Comment: I might have to accept the laconboss answer because his answer is  more canonical and focus on the core of the problem Sorry :(