# Track Rendering engine in php

Tags: php, tracking

**Track/detect render engine** in php file..

Is there a simple php based test that I can apply to decide which browser is being used?

**I have tried this code,**

```
print_r( strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
```

but **output** is,

```
mozilla/5.0 (x11; ubuntu; linux x86_64; rv:47.0) gecko/20100101 firefox/47.0
```

and I want Webkit, Safari... [browser rendering engine](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/61819/browser-rendering-engine)

Please anyone can help me...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a user agent string sniffer to work out the most likely match.

I would suggest using the free API provided by [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php). as it is kept up to date.

**That being said**, DON'T use sniffing for feature determination or providing different content. Both of these are [bad ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661213/why-is-browser-sniffing-not-a-recommended-practice) for a number of reasons.